# Glade-3 for Ada

Tags: ada, glade, gtk2

I am trying to use Glade 3 for my Ada programs on Windows 7. I found a way with version 3.6 but gtk-builder-convert was not recognized as a script. I have tried Google to find a site that explains how to get it working. But it always is for Linux or for another language as Ada. Where can I find a good description how to use glade3 to get a  good basic project.

Comment: My experience is with Glade 2 on Linux. How exactly is what you're trying to do "not working"? What exactly are you doing, what's working and what's not working?  The more information and detail you provide in your question, the better the chance that someone can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `gtk-builder-convert` anymore. Glade can save GtkBuilder files directly now, since version 3.6.

If you still want to run `gtk-builder-convert` anyway, then you need to install Python. It's a Python script.